highlight rows for different values in excel
I have

I want to highlight each row that has a different value to the one above it in a different colour. Makes it easier to view all the category 3, for example, especially when I have lots of columns, and it is easier than filtering on each value to view


This question is similar to: Excel: Conditional formatting for clusters of values. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use an extra column to determine what rows to highlight:



id
category
highlight




1
1
=IF(B2=B1,C1,IF(ISTEXT(C1),1,C1+1))


2
2
=IF(B3=B2,C2,IF(ISTEXT(C2),1,C2+1))


3
3
=IF(B4=B3,C3,IF(ISTEXT(C3),1,C3+1))


4
3
=IF(B5=B4,C4,IF(ISTEXT(C4),1,C4+1))


5
4
=IF(B6=B5,C5,IF(ISTEXT(C5),1,C5+1))


6
4
=IF(B7=B6,C6,IF(ISTEXT(C6),1,C6+1))


7
4
=IF(B8=B7,C7,IF(ISTEXT(C7),1,C7+1))


8
6
=IF(B9=B8,C8,IF(ISTEXT(C8),1,C8+1))


9
6
=IF(B10=B9,C9,IF(ISTEXT(C9),1,C9+1))


10
6
=IF(B11=B10,C10,IF(ISTEXT(C10),1,C10+1))


11
3
=IF(B12=B11,C11,IF(ISTEXT(C11),1,C11+1))


12
3
=IF(B13=B12,C12,IF(ISTEXT(C12),1,C12+1))


13
3
=IF(B14=B13,C13,IF(ISTEXT(C13),1,C13+1))



Then you can use conditional formatting with this formula:
=ISEVEN($C1)

